# Remove area code from Telephonenumber

Tags: c#

How to remove the coutrycode from telphonumber.

the number could come in this format.

```
4770300000
004770300000
+4770300000
4670300000
```

I would like to remove countrycodes to be abile to match does number against.

```
070300000
```

Comment: What are the country code rules for your application? As far as I know a country code can be 1-3 numerals long. Do you know how long a local telephone number should be?

Comment: is there always a countrycode in front or sometimes not?  Are these from all countries or a limited list of countries...?

Comment: @Oded it is even more complex
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

Comment: @Stofke - Which is why I am asking for clarification. Is it always one country? Several? All of them?

Answer (score 2):

The following should replace any valid country code (starting with "00" or "+") with a leading zero.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^(00|\+)(1|2[078]|2[1234569][0-9]|3[0123469]|3[578][0-9]|4[013456789]|42[0-9]|5[09][0-9]|5[12345678]|6[0123456]|6[789][0-9]|7|8[0578][0-9]|8[123469]|9[0123458]|9[679][0-9])", "0");
```

Comment: Note that some countries do not use zero to indicate area codes. Norway, for example, does not have the concept of area codes, and in North America, "1" is used rather than "0". For starters.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a list of expected country codes? If so (assuming for this example that you're just looking for 47 and 46):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\+|\b00|\b)4[67]", "0");
```

would change

```
4770300000 004770300000 +4770300000 4670300000
```

into

```
070300000 070300000 070300000 070300000
```

However, it would also trigger on a phone number where the country code and area code have been omitted, if it happens to start with 47 or 46. To guard against this, you might want to add a lookahead assertion that checks that at least 8 (or whatever is reasonable) digits follow the presumed country code.

So

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\+|\b00|\b)4[67](?=\d{8})", "0");
```

would change

```
4770300000 004770300000 +4770300000 460000
```

into

```
070300000 070300000 070300000 460000
```

If your input string is supposed to consist entirely of a phone number (as opposed to phone numbers embedded somewhere in a longer text), then you might want to use

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^(\+|00)4[67](?=\d{8})", "0");
```

instead. Thanks to Michael for the suggestion!

Comment: I would probably go the other way - getting the last 8 characters and prepending with a 0.

Comment: @Oded: Good idea, if phone numbers are always of the same length. In many countries they aren't.

Comment: That's the assumption (one country only), though the OP didn't provide enough information to determine one way or another.

Comment: You really, *really* want to anchor those regular expressions at the beginning of the string. Edited.

Comment: Well, 46 is Sweden where you have two- or three-digit area codes. I don't know if areas with a three-digit code have shorter local phone numbers, though. So yes, more info please :)

Comment: In Sweden, there are area codes of 2, 3 or 4 digits, including the leading 0. Subscriber numbers range from 5 to 8 digits. Usually longer area codes means shorter subscriber numbers, but phone number lengths are not uniform.

Comment: @Michael: It seems your edit was rejected, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: @Tim - Indeed. I simply changed the regular expressions to each include a `^` immediately at the beginning. The reason being that otherwise, they will match 0046 and 0047 inside phone numbers, which are perfectly valid number sequences. (Not so much a concern with the one including a look-ahead, but still I see no reason not to anchor it.)

Comment: hmm, If i have a list how to do then. something like this:        

 static int[] _area = { 46, 47, 32};

        public string RemoveAreaCode (string phonenumber)
        {
            var result = Regex.Replace(phonenumber, @"(\+|00|\b)4[67]", "0");
            return result;
        } how to do then ?

Comment: @Karl - Wait a minute, area code or country code? Two entirely different things with very different implications. If you meant to say country code, with an array like that, loop over it and either construct a composite regular expression, or call `Replace()` once for each country code.

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated. Both country codes and national numbers varies in length. In addition there are regional codes which some countries use and some don't. And then there's the optional leading '+', or '00'. Not to mention the emergency numbers.

But; Google to the rescue! [This](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library solves your problem - in addition to a lot of other telephone number juggling. And it's ported to all major languages.

E.g. Here's how to strip away any country code from a number:

```
PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance().Parse(phoneno, "").NationalNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If the phone number 070300000 has a fixed length you can get from the whole number only this length I mean f.e. 9 last numbers